Saving a column to an xml file
Hi I am trying to save the content of a column(contains xml information) from a data frame to an xml file. Whenever i run my program i get the error "col should be Column" indicating that when i call my function that saves the content of the column to an xml file, it is saying that it doesn't recognize the column as a column. I have tried using an UDF with it but get the same error. I upload a picture of my code below, any suggestion would help!
My code:
from pyspark.sql import Sparksession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StringType,StructField
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = Sparksession.builder \
    .appName("xml column to file") \
    .getOrCreate()

xml_data = ['<data><name>John</name><age>30</age><city>New York</city></data>']
first_df = spark.createDataFrame([(xml_data)], ["xml_snippet"])

def column_to_xml(df_column):
    xml_inner_data = df_column
    schema = StructType([StructField("xml_column", StringType(),True)])
    innerdf = spark.createDataFrame([(xml,) for xml in xml_inner_data], schema)
    xml_column = innerdf.select("xml_column")
    xml_deta = xml_column.rdd.map(lambda row: row["xml_column"]).collect()
    with open("xml_file.xml", "w") as f:
        for xml_str in xml_deta:
            f.write(xml_str)

first_df = first_df.withColumn("new_column", column_to_xml(F.col('xml_snippet')))

The error I get:
AssertionError: col should be Column
I tried calling my function directly on the column using .withColumn but when i run the code it doesn't recognize the column i made from the data frame as column. I also tried using a UDF but got the same error.

Arguments to withColumn need to return column objects, not perform side-effects such as writing files to disk... I also don't think you can create a dataframe within a UDF. Why do you need Spark for this?

@OneCricketeer thank you for the feed back, I’m using spark for a school project, how would u go about saving the content of the column to an xml file?

I just wouldn't use Spark. You've got a single Python string, not a large dataset that warrants using Spark, so open a file and write to it rather than creating any dataframe

@OneCricketeer what if I’m planning to use a big dataset, I just wanted to test it out on a smaller dataset first before fully implementing it

Given an existing dataframe, then I'd select the column and collect it locally to the driver, then loop over each row and write each row to a unique file.... Otherwise, Spark would create many separate files on remote executor filesystems since it's a distributed process, not just one local xml file
